# How to send HTML email using linux command line

Tags: html, linux, email, send

I need to send email with html format. I have only linux command line and command "mail".

Currently have used:

```
echo "To: address@example.com" > /var/www/report.csv
echo "Subject: Subject" >> /var/www/report.csv
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" >> /var/www/report.csv

echo "<html>" >> /var/www/report.csv
mysql -u ***** -p***** -H -e "select * from users LIMIT 20" dev >> /var/www/report.csv
echo "</html>" >> /var/www/report.csv

mail -s "Built notification" address@example.com < /var/www/report.csv
```

But in my mail-agent i get only plain/text.

[image]

Comment: Readers of answers to this question beware: there are several different programs called `mail`, for example `heirloom-mailx` and `bsd-mailx` on Debian jessie. If a `mail` command from an answer here doesn't work for you, you're probably using the wrong `mail`. Refer to your distribution's package manager to install the correct package, and use the specific name of that binary (e.g. `bsd-mailx` on Debian) to resolve that issue. More details on this here: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx_history.html

Answer (score 65):

This worked for me:

```
echo "<b>HTML Message goes here</b>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" foo@example.com
```

Comment: I'd say that's a bug in OSX's implementation of mail, though it'd need to be combined with other bugs to be exploitable.  I'm sure there would be a few web scripts around that don't properly check for carriage returns in what they insert into subject lines.

Comment: works on AIX 7.1.0.0! Oh, and word to the wise, the backticks don't work (in ksh) but the `$( )` do.

Comment: Worked on Debian Wheezy

Comment: Works on Godaddy and Amazon Linux

Comment: Works on Fedora 29

Comment: Best solution, because it relies only on `mail` and its most basic switches (`-s`). Mail on my BSD-based system does not have `-a` nor `--append` - this worked.

Comment: How would you attach csv file with html body?

Comment: Works on Alpine 3.12.0

Comment: Mighty fine solution!!!! TY

Comment: Doesn't work in Oracle Linux 7.4. Getting the context as text along with <b> tag.

Answer (score 47):

My version of mail does not have `--append` and it too smart for the `echo -e \n`-trick (it simply replaces \n with space). It does, however, have `-a`:

```
mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "Built notification" address@example.com < /var/www/report.html
```

Comment: Works on ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, mail set to bsd-mailx

Comment: I use this way `echo \`curl -L www.google.es\` | mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "website content" email@email.com` instead of `<`. For my convenience, i create a /usr/local/bin script to bypass the most of the command. I just use `wmail url email`

Comment: I tried it but SpamAssassin gave me lower score than I got without the -a "Cont...", maybe beacuse I didn't have text as html

Comment: I get no such file or directory for content type with mail and mailx

Comment: I also get "Content-type: text/html: No such file or directory".  Are you sure the "-a" is right ?

Comment: does not work on OSX

Answer (score 37):

## Send email using command Line

*This answer is over 11 years old, these days I use python's `import ezgmail` for a 4 line plug, auth and play solution*

Create a file named `tmp.html` with the following contents:

```html
<b>my bold message</b>
```

Next, paste the following into the command line (parentheses and all):

```bash
(
  echo To: youremail@blah.com
  echo From: el@defiant.com
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; "
  echo Subject: a logfile
  echo
  cat tmp.html
) | sendmail -t
```

The mail will be dispatched including a bold message due to the `<b>` element.

## Shell Script

As a script, save the following as `email.sh`:

```
ARG_EMAIL_TO="recipient@domain.com"
ARG_EMAIL_FROM="Your Name <you@host.com>"
ARG_EMAIL_SUBJECT="Subject Line"

(
  echo "To: ${ARG_EMAIL_TO}"
  echo "From: ${ARG_EMAIL_FROM}"
  echo "Subject: ${ARG_EMAIL_SUBJECT}"
  echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'"
  echo
  cat contents.html
) | sendmail -t
```

Create a file named `contents.html` in the same directory as the `email.sh` script that resembles:

```html
<html><head><title>Subject Line</title></head>
<body>
  <p style='color:red'>HTML Content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Run `email.sh`. When the email arrives, the `HTML Content` text will appear red.

## Related

- [How to send a html email with the bash command "sendmail"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333097/how-to-send-a-html-email-with-the-bash-command-sendmail)

Comment: `echo | cat msg-headers - msg-body | sendmail -t` (with `msg-headers` and `msg-body` as text files containing your headers and body, respectively)

Comment: This worked for me but how can we add an attachment when we are using sendmail

Comment: @DileepGogula See http://www.zedwood.com/article/bash-send-mail-with-an-attachment (linked from the "Related" part above in two clicks)

Answer (score 10):

On OS X (10.9.4), `cat` works, and is easier if your email is already in a file:

```
cat email_template.html  | mail -s "$(echo -e "Test\nContent-Type: text/html")" karl@marx.com
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that when redirecting a file into 'mail' like that, it's used for the message body only. Any headers you embed in the file will go into the body instead.

Try:

```
mail --append="Content-type: text/html" -s "Built notification" address@example.com < /var/www/report.csv
```

--append lets you add arbitrary headers to the mail, which is where you should specify the content-type and content-disposition. There's no need to embed the `To` and `Subject` headers in your file, or specify them with --append, since you're implicitly setting them on the command line already (-s is the subject, and address@example.com automatically becomes the `To`).

Comment: don't have that option on my mail command mail: invalid option -- a
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]

Comment: @nylund: `mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)`. this is off ubuntu 12.04, but will be in older versions as well, given this answer's almost 3 years old now.

Answer (score 3):

With heirloom-mailx you can change sendmail program to your hook script, replace headers there and then use sendmail.

The script I use (`~/bin/sendmail-hook`):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '1,/^$/{
s,^\(Content-Type: \).*$,\1text/html; charset=utf-8,g
s,^\(Content-Transfer-Encoding: \).*$,\18bit,g
}' | sendmail $@
```

This script changes the values in the mail header as follows:

- `Content-Type:` to `text/html; charset=utf-8`
- `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` to `8bit` (not sure if this is really needed).

To send HTML email:

```
mail -Ssendmail='~/bin/sendmail-hook' \
    -s "Built notification" address@example.com < /var/www/report.csv
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work in a function, but you can indeed use this as a separate executable file. This worked when other suggestions on this page did not.

Comment: You can't get this work as a function because mail's process spawned don't have access to functions in your bash script

Comment: [Can't figure out how to take this to a chat or PM.] Could I source my mail command? `. mail -Ssendmail='~/bin/sendmail-hook' -s "Subject" address@example.com < inputfile`

Comment: You cannot source it, because it is binary. You should create own bash script with those commands and (if you need that) source it.

Answer (score 2):

Very old question, however it ranked high when I googled a question about this.

Find the answer here:

[Sending HTML mail using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with similar problem (with mail) in one of my git's post_receive hooks and finally I found out, that sendmail actually works better for that kind of things, especially if you know a bit of how e-mails are constructed (and it seems like you know). I know this answer comes very late, but maybe it will be of some use to others too. I made use of heredoc operator and use of the feature, that it expands variables, so it can also run inlined scripts. Just check this out (bash script):

```
#!/bin/bash
recipients=(
    'john@example.com'
    'marry@not-so-an.example.com'
#   'naah@not.this.one'
);
sender='highly-automated-reporter@example.com';
subject='Oh, who really cares, seriously...';
sendmail -t <<-MAIL
    From: ${sender}
    `for r in "${recipients[@]}"; do echo "To: ${r}"; done;`
    Subject: ${subject}
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

    <html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/></head>
    <body><p>Ladies and gents, here comes the report!</p>
    <pre>`mysql -u ***** -p***** -H -e "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 20"`</pre>
    </body></html>
MAIL
```

Note of backticks in the MAIL part to generate some output and remember, that `<<-` operator strips only tabs (not spaces) from the beginning of lines, so in that case copy-paste will not work (you need to replace indentation with proper tabs). Or use `<<` operator and make no indentation at all. Hope this will help someone. Of course you can use backticks outside o MAIL part and save the output into some variable, that you can later use in the MAIL part — matter of taste and readability. And I know, `#!/bin/bash` does not always work on every system.

Answer (score 2):

I found a really easy solution: add to the mail command the modifier -aContent-Type:text/html.

In your case would be:

```
mail -aContent-Type:text/html -s "Built notification" address@example.com < /var/www/report.csv
```

Comment: But I get no such file or directory when am using this

Comment: @eightStacker: is there a file called report.csv in your /var/www directory? If not you should replace that with the file you want to send. Also address@example.com is an example, you have to replace that with the actual destinatary of your message

Comment: @Zafar same thing I told eightStacker :)

Comment: `-a` option is for "attachment"... I'm working with version "12.5 7/5/10" on a **CentOS** 7.4 server; in other comments they talk about `--append`, and this is not even an option ... why so many _(apparently)_ **mail** implementations?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188 which discusses the many `mail` implementations and how to know which one you have.

Answer (score 1):

you should use "append" mode redirection `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: I think this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
echo "To: address@example.com" > /var/www/report.csv
echo "Subject: Subject" >> /var/www/report.csv
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0" >> /var/www/report.csv
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" >> /var/www/report.csv
echo "Content-Disposition: inline" >> /var/www/report.csv

echo "<html>" >> /var/www/report.csv
mysql -u ***** -p***** -H -e "select * from users LIMIT 20" dev >> /var/www/report.csv
echo "</html>" >> /var/www/report.csv

mail -s "Built notification" address@example.com < /var/www/report.csv
```

Comment: This does not work.

    $ lsb_release -a    
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
    Release: 10.04
    Codename: lucid

Comment: @Simone, this is not working perfectly because of order of **MIME-Version** and **Content-Tye**. You need to put this information prior to **Subject** to work for most of the unix/linux flavor.