# Send Html page As Email using "mutt"

Tags: bash, mutt

I have been using mutt to send emails from inside another application &
it works fine. I have to send html files and currently I have to send
them as attachments. So I use

```
mutt -s "hi" -a attach.html user@domain.com < /dev/null
```

But if I try to send the html file as the body as follows

```
mutt -e content_type=text/html Email address -s "subject" < test.html
```

then instead of the html file i get the source text of the html file.

Is there any way that I can make the body of the message as html
instead of plain text???

Answer (score 64):

When I try your command, mutt is telling me that `content_type=text/html` is an unknown command. So you have to use the "set" command to make this work:

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" Email address -s "subject" < test.html
```

That worked in my tests.

Comment: it return : error in command line "content_type" : unknown command and i get the source code insted of html body ??

Comment: @eldorado what version of mutt are you using? apparently the "content_type"-variable is not available in the version `1.4.x` or before.

Comment: Well, 1.5.21 is the most recent one (and the one i've used for testing the command). But according to the [mutt webpage](http://www.mutt.org/) it's still a development-version. If you can live with it that's okay, otherwise there are other ways to send HTML-mails.

Comment: could you please Give me The other Way TO send Html-mails ?

Comment: @eldorado see [sending HTML mail using a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script). But I have read today that sending HTML-Mails only (that means without multi-part with a text/plain alternative) is increasing the possibility of getting the mail considered as SPAM (I don't have the link so "citation needed").

Answer (score 8):

I tried with mutt 1.6d and that option  -e "set content_type=text/html"  doesn't work for me. After search around i found below command line works for me:

```
mutt -e "my_hdr Content-Type: text/html" test@yahoo.com  -s "subject" < mytest.html
```

Reference here

[LinuxQuestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/echo-mypage-htm-%7C-mutt-s-hello-news-myemail@gmail-com-624938/)

Comment: This one, on mutt 1.4 will send two headers content-type, one for plain text, other for html. what the client will show up is up to then... gmail will show the plain text, so be careful

Comment: Just for the record, this also works for version 1.5.20.

Answer (score 6):

my mutt version is 1.4.x, and I also cannot set content_type=text/html, it is reported as unknown variable.

and I checked the [mutt doc](http://www.mutt.org/#doc), the **content_type** is only supported by version 1.5.x, such as the latest version 1.5.21.

obviously, html mail was not supported by version 1.4.x.

Answer (score 5):

I use Mutt 1.5.23 to send an html email with embedded image, and this works for me.
`mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" Email -s "subject" -a pic.png  < test.html`

file test.html:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <img src="cid:pic.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of an HTML email, you'll see at minimum something like:

```
Subject: test html mail
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4

--bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

*hi!*

--bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p><b>hi!</b></p>

--bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4--
```

So, you have to create a "Content-Type:" header, and add the boundaries above the text-only version, and above and below the HTML version.

Given the amount of hand-crafting required, you might as well hand the message over to sendmail instead of mutt.

Comment: Mutt does not allow you to insert a Content-Type header. The only way is through the command line.

Comment: @e18r so it does allow you to insert a content-type header, with `-e`.