# Different Content Types in email

Tags: email, mime-types, content-type, html-email

I was reviewing the source of some emails sent to me and noticed in one that the content type for the text part is different from the HTML part - see below.

```
--_----------=_MCPart_1153762294
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii";

--_----------=_MCPart_1153762294
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I was wondering if this is okay to have this? The email was sent from Monkey Wrench via MailChimp server.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the complete headers and body would be necessary to fully answer your question, but given what we have:  **Yes, it's okay to have this.**  Presumably the message itself is `multipart`, and these are snippets from two of the parts in the message body.

Edit: Here's a more complete message that I shamelessly stole (from: [Send Html page As Email using "mutt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805783/send-html-page-as-email-using-mutt)).  It includes all the parts you mention, and it is perfectly legit if somewhat simplistic:

```
Subject: test html mail
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4

--bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

*hi!*

--bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p><b>hi!</b></p>

--bcaec520ea5d6918e204a8cea3b4--
```