# send html content using mail command

Tags: html, email

I was trying to send an html file using mail commnad, but the mail contents alignment is not working.

Here is the command used to send the mail

> /bin/mail -s "$(echo -e "log -  $date\nFrom: ABC \n";)" abc@gmail.com < /root/test

After searching, I found that we need to add "Content-Type" on the header. So I have added it on the header and its worked, but the From header is not working and some additional info showing on the mail.

Here is the command I used to send mail :

> /bin/mail -s "$(echo -e "log -  $datet\nContent-Type: text/html\nFrom: ABC \n";)" abc@gmail.com < /root/test

The additional info showing on the mail while adding content-type is as follows : 
From: ABC User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable = =20

Could anyone please tell me how to send html using mail command with all the above options?

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/how-do-i-send-html-email-using-linux-mail-command

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already saw this post.  I have tried with mailx command too, but was getting content-type error : 

mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Subject" abc@gmail.com < /root/test
Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory

Comment: The error indicates that your version of `mailx` treats `-a` as an attachment instead of an additional header. Which OS and which version of mailx?

Comment: Update: The first answer in the linked question says clearly that there is more than one version of `mailx` and you need the one "from mailutils on Ubuntu or Debian's bsd-mailx"

Comment: I am using CentOS 6.5

Comment: Get the sources for `mailutils` from http://mailutils.org/ and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutt` instead. See this question: [Send Html page As Email using "mutt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805783/send-html-page-as-email-using-mutt)

This question how do what you want but you need a version of `mail` which supports adding headers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/how-do-i-send-html-email-using-linux-mail-command

If your Linux distro doesn't come with one, then download the sources for `mailutils` from http://mailutils.org/ and compile them. See this question: https://superuser.com/questions/243152/how-to-send-email-message-content-as-html-rather-than-plain-text