# Send a Dynamic Html message using shell scripts

Tags: shell, sendmail

I am following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script). 
I have to send a dynamic html such that its content would change similiar to JSPs.
How can that be achieved using shell scripts?

Comment: I think the link that you gave, provide what you need?

Comment: You just put variables in the echo statements. That's it.

Comment: Are you able to send dummy mails?

Comment: Would be useful to use [mutt](https://www.tecmint.com/send-mail-from-command-line-using-mutt-command/) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using python, if you want dynamic content, means you will store variables, which means you may eventually need a db or you can access csv from python, you can simply call the process shell from python by

```
from subprocess import call
print subprocess.Popen("echo Hello World", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

now you can simple compose the command from python, and accessing db becomes easy, multi-threading and etc...
i would have made this a comment but i can't comment