# Reading HTML in a string message while sending mail in bash script

Tags: html, bash, email

I have my script for sending email to some user in Linux. I want to read the string content as HTML in bash, but bash is not able to read string as HTML.

Start of Script:

```
body ='
 Dear $user,
<p> The password for your account is due to expire on in 14 days. and must be changed.<br>
<p>You can reset your password by visiting the Password Reset Portal.</p>
<p><a href="https://google.com/">Google</a> </p>
<p>You can contact the XYZ Team in case of any issue. </p>'

#send email
user='ABC'
email="abc@gmail.co."
from="xyz@gmail.com"    
echo $body1 | mail -s test -r $from $email
```

I wanted my message to user will be shown as below and read string as html

```
Dear ABC,
The password for your account is due to expire on in 14 days. and must be changed.
You can reset your password by visiting the Password Reset Portal.
Google
You can contact the XYZ Team in case of any issue
```

However bash is reading the body as a string and not as HTML as below

```
Dear ABC,
<p> The password for your account is due to expire on in 14 days. and must be changed.</p><br>
<p>You can reset your password by visiting the Password Reset Portal.</p>
<p><a href="https://google.com/">Google</a> </p>
<p>You can contact the XYZ Team in case of any issue. </p>
```

Please anyone can help me on this.

I have tried the answers from the link [Sending HTML mail using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script) but i am not succeeded.

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-to-send-html-email-using-linux-command-line)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send HTML email using linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-to-send-html-email-using-linux-command-line)

Comment: i tried using the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-to-send-html-email-using-linux-command-line  but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `mail` is a generic name for quite a few different programs (depending on OS and distro), and sometimes `mail` is a symlink to some other program (eg, mailx).  Net result is that it's going to be hard to troubleshoot your issue without a good bit more detail on the program you're using called `mail`.  This in turn can make (semi) portability of scripts a real b*tch (even between hosts in the same domain).  For these reasons I tend to use `sendmail` when I need to do some special formatting on the body of an email.

The second issue is that most `mail` programs need to be instructed to interpret (html) tags.  This typically includes adding (at the top of the email) the clauses `MIME-VERSION: 1.0` and `Content-Type: text/html`.

One simple example you could start with:

```
body="Dear $user,
<p> The password for your account is due to expire on in 14 days. and must be changed.<br>
<p>You can reset your password by visiting the Password Reset Portal.</p>
<p><a href=\"https://google.com/\">Google</a> </p>
<p>You can contact the XYZ Team in case of any issue. </p>"

email="abc@gmail.co."
from="xyz@gmail.com"

echo "Subject: My test subject
To: ${email}
From: ${from}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
<html><body>
${body}
</body></html>" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

NOTE: Verify the path on your host for `sendmail`.

NOTE: If you don't have `sendmail` installed then that's a whole 'nother post since the sysadmin will need to setup a config file to tell `sendmail` how to process (e)mail messages (eg, what's the name of the smtp server?).

With this basic wrapper you should be able to add more html tags as needed.