# Linux mail command : HTML content in office 365 email is visible as plain text while it is correctly visible in gmail

Tags: linux, html-email

I'm trying to send out some HTML content via email using mail linux command. I'm on CentOS 7.

```
mail -s "$(echo -e "This is Subject\nContent-Type: text/html")"  gpsanjeewaa@gmail.com pradeep.sanjeewa@axiatadigitallabs.com <  /var/www/html/report.html
```

Office365

[image]

Gmail

[image]

What is the reason for this different behavior and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Look at the source of the sent email. Probably your MIME structure is botched.

Comment: Hi @Robert: Can you elaborate more on how to check this?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Office365, hence: In Gmail, open your email, then click the three vertical dots in the circle on the right. Select "show original". The message source will be at the bottom of the page. Check with the [MIME standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). Maybe adding another header with the subject doesn't work as expected. Maybe you can fix it by adding a `\r` with the `\n` to separate headers. MIME calls for CRLF as line endings. Compare your email to other emails that display fine. How do they differ?

Comment: Hi @Robert, In both cases MIME version is 1.0. Checking source, I noticed something related to "Content type". For office 365 "Content-Type: text/plain". In gmail source there were two fields with the same name "Content-Type". At one place it is "text/html" and at other place it is "text/plain"