# How to send a png file embedded in a mail via command line on linux?

Tags: linux, image, email, embed

I was trying to send a png file in a body of an email via command line. I have been using the following command:

```
uuencode file.png file.png| mail user@example.com
```

but it attaches the file in the mail, rather than embedding it in body.
Could you please tell me how to send mail with png file embedded in mail ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a mime HTML email a la:

[How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/4312865#4312865)

Then take the headers (all the lines before the first boundary), remove them from that input and add them individually with the -a command after mail such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262421/2244213