# linux mail adding content type headers not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mailx

i am using **mail** command to send mails from my linux system.

The problem i am getting is the Content type of the mail is always as `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.

I am sending the html content and it is displaying as plain text.

This is what i have tried

```
1)
body="From: me@example.org
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: MIME Test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
This is a test.
</body>
</html>";

echo $body| mail -s "testing purpose" reciever@gmail.com
```

*this didn't worked*

*i put this html in a file called test.html in $tempfile
and tried to execute like this*

```
2)
mail -a 'MIME-Version: 1.0' -a 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' "server details" "receiver@gmail.com" < $tempfile
```

But nothing has worked, please suggest me regarding this (please only using mail not sendmail/mutt).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<b>HTML Message goes here</b>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" foo@example.com
```

[How to send HTML email using linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-send-html-mail-using-linux-command-line)