# Mailx send html message

Tags: html, linux, email, mailx

I want to send a html message with Mailx. When I try the following command

```
mailx -s "Subject"  user@gmail.com  < email.html
```

I get the content of email.html in plain text. In the message the header Content-Type is set to text/plain. The -a option tries to send a file so I didn't find out how to modify the header. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457922/linux-mail-adding-content-type-headers-not-working) almost worked, it sets well the Content-Type to text/html but doesn't substitute the default Content-Type which is text/plain.

```
mailx -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" user@gmail.com  < email.html
```

gives this result :

```
From: send@gmail.com
To: user@gmail.com
Subject: This is the subject
Content-Type: text/html
Message-ID: <538d7b66.Xs0x9HsxnJKUFWuI%maikeul06@gmail.com>
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
 boundary="=_538d7b66.z5gaIQnlwb1f/AOkuuC+GwF1evCaG/XIHQMbMMxbY6satTjK"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--=_538d7b66.z5gaIQnlwb1f/AOkuuC+GwF1evCaG/XIHQMbMMxbY6satTjK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

<html>
<body>
<p>Helo wolrd</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PS : I also tried with uuencode. When I try to display the message in the webmail I get a blank page...

Comment: There are multiple variants of `mailx` in common use. You may be better off with `mutt` if you can't be sure which of them is installed. See this near-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188

Answer (score 36):

It's easy, if your `mailx` command supports the [`-a`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/mail.1.html) (append header) option:

```
$ mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "my subject" user@gmail.com < email.html
```

If it doesn't, try using [`sendmail`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sendmail):

```
# create a header file
$ cat mailheader
To: user@gmail.com
Subject: my subject
Content-Type: text/html

# send
$ cat mailheader email.html | sendmail -t
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to do so. Seems I'm gonna have to configure sendmail to validate your answer ;)

Comment: regarding `man mailx` the flag `-a attaches a given file to the massage`. There seems to be different mailx versions around http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15463

Comment: The default with RHEL 6 (don't have 7 at my fingers) is that /bin/mail is /bin/mailx. With mailx -a is "append file". With mail that ISN'T mailx -a is append header.

Comment: A bit late for user3580716 but any linux system that can send mail should have a sendmail command that will work.  It may not be actually sendmail, but a compatible mode of the system mailer (postfix, exim, whatever), but it should work for this case.

Answer (score 17):

There are many different versions of mail around. When you go beyond mail -s subject to1@address1 to2@address2

- With some mailx implementations, e.g. from mailutils on Ubuntu or
  Debian's bsd-mailx, it's easy, because there's an option for that.

  ```
  mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Subject" to@address <test.html
  ```
- With the Heirloom mailx, there's no convenient way. One possibility
  to insert arbitrary headers is to set editheaders=1 and use an
  external editor (which can be a script).

  ```
  ## Prepare a temporary script that will serve as an editor.

  ## This script will be passed to ed.
  temp_script=$(mktemp)
  cat <<'EOF' >>"$temp_script"
  1a
  Content-Type: text/html
  .
  $r test.html
  w
  q
  EOF
  ## Call mailx, and tell it to invoke the editor script
  EDITOR="ed -s $temp_script" heirloom-mailx -S editheaders=1 -s "Subject" to@address <<EOF
  ~e
  .
  EOF
  rm -f "$temp_script"
  ```
- With a general POSIX mailx, I don't know how to get at headers.

If you're going to use any mail or mailx, keep in mind that

- This isn't portable even within a given Linux distribution. For example, both Ubuntu and Debian have several alternatives for mail and mailx.
- When composing a message, mail and mailx treats lines beginning with ~ as commands. If you pipe text into mail, you need to arrange for this text not to contain lines beginning with ~.

If you're going to install software anyway, you might as well install something more predictable than mail/Mail/mailx. For example, mutt. With Mutt, you can supply most headers in the input with the -H option, but not Content-Type, which needs to be set via a mutt option.

```
mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s 'hello' 'to@address' <test.html
```

Or you can invoke sendmail directly. There are several versions of sendmail out there, but they all support sendmail -t to send a mail in the simplest fashion, reading the list of recipients from the mail. (I think they don't all support Bcc:.) On most systems, sendmail isn't in the usual $PATH, it's in /usr/sbin or /usr/lib.

```
cat <<'EOF' - test.html | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
To: to@address
Subject: hello
Content-Type: text/html

EOF
```

Comment: For Heirloom mailx, the solution will not work, because content-type header will be ignored.  
When a message is edited while being composed, its header is included in the editable text. **'To:', 'Cc:', 'Bcc:', 'Subject:', 'From:', 'Reply-To:', 'Sender:', and 'Organization:'** fields are accepted within the header, other fields are ignored.

Answer (score 16):

I had successfully used the following on Arch Linux (where the `-a` flag is used for attachments) for several years:

```
mailx -s "The Subject $(echo -e \\\nContent-Type: text/html)" user@gmail.com < email.html
```

This appended the Content-Type header to the subject header, which worked great until a recent update. Now the new line is filtered out of the `-s` subject. Presumably, this was done to improve security.

Instead of relying on hacking the subject line, I now use a bash subshell:

```
(
    echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\n"
    cat mail.html
 ) | mail -s "The Subject" -t user@gmail.com
```

And since we are really only using `mailx`'s subject flag, it seems there is no reason not to switch to `sendmail` as suggested by @dogbane:

```
(
    echo "To: user@gmail.com"
    echo "Subject: The Subject"
    echo "Content-Type: text/html"
    echo
    cat mail.html
) | sendmail -t
```

The use of bash subshells avoids having to create a temporary file.

Comment: Strictly speaking, shouldn't you also have a `MIME-Version: 1.0` header?

Comment: should your mailx subject echo command include the closing parenthesis?

Comment: I used the 1st method you suggested, and it worked, but I can't attach files this way. Is it even possible when sending html content?

Comment: The first subshell method did not work for me.  The html text was just pasted in as text.

Comment: I find the echo escape-escape-escape... hard to follow. I find this one easier: `echo "${message}" | mailx -s "$( printf '%s\n%s' "${subject}" "Content-Type text/html" )" "${recipient}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
EMAILCC=" -c user1@dominio.cl,user2@dominio.cl"
TURNO_EMAIL="user@dominio.cl"

mailx $EMAILCC -s "$(echo "Status: Control Aplicactivo \nContent-Type: text/html")" $TURNO_EMAIL < tmp.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "-a" mail and mailx in Centos7 is "attach file" not "append header."  My shortest path to a solution on Centos7 from here: 
[stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/how-do-i-send-html-email-using-linux-mail-command)

Basically:

```
yum install mutt
mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s 'My subject' me@my.com < msg.html
```

Comment: Indeed, using Mutt is a much more reliable way, especially with CentOS 6. There is literally no need to waste time any more time trying to get "mail" or "mailx" to work with custom headers...

Answer (score -3):

If you use AIX try this
This will attach a text file and include a HTML body
If this does not work catch the output in the /var/spool/mqueue

```
#!/usr/bin/kWh
if (( $# < 1 ))
 then
  echo "\n\tSyntax: $(basename) MAILTO SUBJECT BODY.html ATTACH.txt "
  echo "\tmailzatt"
  exit
fi
export MAILTO=${1-noreply@visweb.co.za}
MAILFROM=$(whoami)
SUBJECT=${2-"mailzatt"}
export BODY=${3-/apps/bin/attch.txt}
export ATTACH=${4-/apps/bin/attch.txt}
export HST=$(hostname)
#export BODY="/wrk/stocksum/report.html"
#export ATTACH="/wrk/stocksum/Report.txt"
#export MAILPART=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
#export MAILPART_BODY=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
export MAILPART="==".$(date +%d%S)."===" ## Generates Unique ID
export MAILPART_BODY="==".$(date +%d%Sbody)."===" ## Generates Unique ID
(
echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "From: mailmate@$HST "
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$MAILPART\""
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$MAILPART_BODY\""
 echo ""
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY--"
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
 echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$(basename $ATTACH)\""
 echo ""
 cat $ATTACH
 echo ""
 echo "--${MAILPART}--"
  ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: That might work, but it's pretty horrible.  The redundant `export` statements should probably already scare you a little.

Comment: I'm guessing `#!/bin/kWh` is a typo for `#!/bin/ksh`, or is there really a shell called kilowatt-hours on AIX?

Comment: Many better scripts at this near-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script