# shell does not keep bold format when using mail command

Tags: shell, email

I use shell script as below to get the string partly bold which works and results in the correct string echo'd in the terminal:

```
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
str="${bold}ERROR${normal} detail text"
echo -e "$str"
```

It does not work together with `mail` command:

```
echo -e "$str" | mail -s "daily notification" 123@abc.com
```

I receive an email with "[1mERROR", But not "**ERROR**", anyone know why?

Comment: Because the output from `tput` is the control codes necessary to get your current terminal to display in bold and that doesn't make any sense to put in an email's contents.

Comment: @EtanReisner, thanks for the quick answer. OK, that makes sense. Then is it possible to add the format in the email?

Comment: Yes, use HTML email and HTML formatting.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such concept as "bold text" in plain ASCII (aka `text/plain`), which is what traditional clients such as `mail` and its close relative `mailx` send.  If you compose [`text/enriched`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_text) (which never really took off) or another structured format like `text/html`, [`text/rtf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) etc then the facility is available, but the formatting codes to achieve it will most certainly not be the *terminal* control sequences you produce with `tput`.  These days, the simplest approach is probably to compose your message in HTML, and use a client which can properly set the `Content-Type:` header to reflect this. (Some variants of `mailx` apparently have this, but there are many incompatible ones which don't.)

So the following *might* work (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27693507/874188), if you're lucky and have a compatible `mailx` version:

```
echo '<html><body><p>Test <b>bold</b> text</p></body></html>' |
mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Daily notification" 123@example.com
```

It would be nice if there was a universal formatting language which adapted and scaled to the facilities and conventions for terminals, print, and graphical displays in various form factors; at various times, Unix `roff`, TeX, PostScript (which is still at the heart of PDF) and Microsoft's RTF have showed some promise, but none of them quite made it.  Currently, HTML is the strongest contender in this field in my humble estimation, but still not quite there.

Meanwhile, some modern graphical email clients will display `*bold*` as **bold** and `_italics_` as *italics* even in plain-text messages; and even users who don't see this graphical markup can usually understand and appreciate these conventions.