# Content-Type on line command doesn't work on Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, sendmail, centos6

I´ve tryed many ways (found here), but none works. The problem is that i have limitations to install plugins on this server, i've only  a sendmail with postfix to work with the mail.

The error returned is:

```
sudo mail -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s "test mail" user@domain.com <  TEST.html
--->
Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory
```

i tried `cat TEST.html | mail -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s "test mail" user@domain.com` but it doesn't work too.

The same commands on Ubuntu 14.04 with postfix and works great!

I've found into the man help differences, into the Ubuntu man os "mail" appears that `-a = HEADER`, but into the Centos `-a = "file"` and i cant find any Header reference...

Could you help me please?

Comment: i use heirloom-mailx version for what i can see

Comment: the -a option for mail on centos 6.5 is to attach a file. So it looks like this version of mailx does not support header. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message

Comment: i red that, but the solutions there doesn´t work for me. While i'm trying many things i asked for the installation od the bsd-mailx (my company works that way, i've no permissions to install, so to earn time i have to try everything before)

Answer (score 1):

In case of email you want to send you may easily use lower level tools/programs.
Sendmail or sendmail look alike provided by Exim/Postfix/... are more portable at basic level .

```sh
#!/bin/sh
SUBJECT='test mail'
RECIPIENT='user@domain.com'
FILE='TEST.html'

cat - $FILE <<END | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $RECIPIENT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: $SUBJECT
To: $RECIPIENT

END
```

> **WARNING1:** sendmail breaks long lines (990 bytes).  You may use e.g. `tidy` to reformat html file
>   **WARNING2**: avoid multiline headers (e.g. $Subject) it requires special formatting
>   **WARNING3**: non ASCII characters in `Subject:` and `To:` require extra hacking

Comment: i Tried that, but even the sendmail writes into the log that the mail was succesfully sent... I've no received anyting...

Comment: 1) Add `-v` to sendmail's command line options to check if the message is passed to local sendmail daemon at 127.0.0.1:25 2) Check sendmail daemon log file and sendmail queue content (use `mailq`)

Comment: Done, what i can see in the log then is tha sendmail adds automatically a line with Content-Type = plain/text after mine:

`Return-Path: <user@localdomain>
Received: by localdomain (Postfix, from userid 10015)
  id 9A838212; Thu, 11 Feb 2016 14:43:14 +0100 (CET)
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 14:43:14 +0100
To: eduardo.andres@xx.com
Subject: Test
Content-Type: text/html
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>`

Comment: 1) I fixed mime headers in my code sample 2) your should not get `User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08` when you script uses sendmail directly