# High Priority Mail using mailx

Tags: unix

I have written the mailx command like this

```
echo "${BDY_MSG}" | mailx -r <from_address> -s <subject> <to_address>
```

Now I need to set the priority of this mail.How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to look at your `mailx` manpage to see what options are accepted. Two solutions in increasing order of hack-iness:

- If your `mailx` supports the `-a` option to add an additional header option, you can use `-a "X-Priority:1"`.
- If your `mailx` does not support the `-a` option, you can try to hack it in by using this trick from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message) by adding a newline to the subject: `-s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nX-Priority: 1")"`
- If neither of those work for you, you'll need to try another tool.

Comment: Perfect hack with -s, although double-quotes inside double-quotes seemed not right, it worked exactly as proposed.

Comment: you don't need for a command substitution; using the [ANSI-C Quoting feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) (see [Which shells support ANSI-C quoting? e.g. $'string'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371827/72456)), that could be simply written as `-s 'subject_here'$'\nX-Priority: 1'`.