# How to send a html file using mails in shell script?

Tags: html, bash, shell, outlook, mailx

I want to store my matrix's data in a html file and send a email in outlook ,my code looks as follows:

```
  printf "<!DOCTYPE html>"
  printf "<html>"
  printf "<head>"
  printf "<style>"

  printf "</style>"
  printf "</head>"
  printf "<body>"

  printf "<table>"
    printf "<tr>"
     printf "<th>Total</th>"
      printf "<th>StillFail</th>"
      printf "<th>Pass</th>"
      printf "<th>ScriptError</th>"
      printf "<th>APIName</th>"
    printf "</tr>"
    printf "<tr>"
  echo
       for ((j=1;j<=num_rows;j++)) do
        printf "<tr>"
       for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
              printf "<td>"
              printf "${matrix[$j,$i]}"
              printf  "</td>"
        printf "</tr>"
        done
   echo
   done
  printf "</tr>"
  printf "</table>"

  printf "</body>"
  printf "</html>"
  #mailx -a 'Content-Type: html' -s "my subject" test@example.com < output.html
  mailx -s "TESTING MAIL"</home/test/example/output.html  "test@example.com"
```

I want my output as a well aligned table. Can someone help me on this? TIA

Comment: whats the output for this ? `mailx -a 'Content-Type: html' -s "my subject" tapariak@amazon.com < output.html`

Comment: my script name is parseScript.sh, so when I run this script I run as follows: ./parseScript.sh > output.html ,so that my output should store in output.html and then I am mailing that file using mail

Comment: i dont understand what your are saying anyway your mail is of content-type `text` change it to `html` are you using `mailUtils` ?

Comment: Where to change content type of mail?

Comment: try my answer and let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mailx send html message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message)

Comment: I have already seen that post and that command is not working for me so I asked it again here @icedant

Answer (score 0):

You need to append content-type in header it can be done with [-a](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/mail.1.html) flag in `mailx`

comment your last line and try this

```
mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Test MAIL" test@example.com</home/test/example/output.html
```

**Edit :**

> As per the OP End error : `content-type:texthtml no such file or
>   directory`

*To install `mailutils` in mac*

```
Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
Run in Terminal app:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
Run:
brew install mailutils
```

reference : http://macappstore.org/mailutils/

Comment: it gives me this error : Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory

Comment: did you use single codes for `content-type`? as it is in the answer?

Comment: how did you install `mailx`?

Comment: it was already there when I got this Mac from my company. Possible cause of this problem can be?

Comment: i tried in my linux machine it worked http://imgur.com/86de9Fn

please try the answer in command line and let me know whether you get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150375/discussion-between-arun-pandian-m-and-keshav-taparia).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this for a base:

```
    (
echo "To: ADRESSES"
echo "Subject: SUBJECT"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
echo "HTML code"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -F "NameOfSender" -t
```