# Bash - Send email with html in body

Tags: bash, email, scripting, html-email

I am trying to send e-mail with HTML in the body using mailx comand.

```
cat "messagefile.html" | mailx -s "$client - Error report" -S smtp=smtp://mailserver:26 -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user=USER -S smtp-auth-password=PASS -S from="USER" TOWHOM
```

But is sending the HTML code.

I’ve tried:

- To add *-a “Content-Type*”: seams is not longer supported by my centos version. This was explained here: [Mailx send html message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message) .
- Also I’ve tried to add the content type into the html file . Not working.
- Content type into subject also

The HTML is correct when I view it direct from the server.
Does anyone know a way to do it ?

Thank you all.

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you Luis for the tip. I was in a hurry last night.