# Bash:emailing file content, getting space issue on mail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

i am using simple bash script which stores values in file and those content of file sends to appropriate email.

the output of bash command comes like this:-

[image: shell command output]

but when i sends this output, i am getting like this

[image: email output]

Its not in proper format.
shell script code is as follows-

> ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -4 >> /tmp/abc.txt
>
> mail -s"mail" abc@gmail.com < /tmp/abc.txt

Please help me to sort out this formatting issue.
I am new to bash scripting.

Comment: It looks like the output does contain tabs and spaces just as the bash output, so perhaps your issue is more to do with the font?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a proportional font in your mail client.  Configure it to show plain text in fixed-width formatting, or perhaps use some rich format where you have more control over this.

Incidentally, there is no need to use a temporary file for the output.

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -4 |
mail -s"mail" abc@gmail.com
```

Here's a crude attempt at making it fixed-width HTML:

```
( printf '<html><body><pre>'
  ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -4
  printf '</pre></body></html>\n'
) | mail -s"mail" -a 'Content-type: text/html' abc@gmail.com
```

The `-a` option to `mail` is not portable; perhaps try with `-A` or use `mutt` instead if you are not on a platform where `mail -a` allows you to control the MIME `Content-Type` of your message.  See also [Mailx send html message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message)

Answer (score 0):

think it should preserve the spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
stdout=`ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -4`
echo "<html><body><pre>${stdout}</pre></body></html>" >> ./test.html
mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "mail" abc@gmail.com < ./test.html
```

looks alike this:

```
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
 2583     1 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/jre/ 20.8  0.5
28660 20791 /home/google/android-studio 18.2  5.9
20791 20720 /home/google/android-studio  9.8 25.8
```

Comment: still getting same space issue on mail.

Comment: `<pre>${stdout}</pre>` should also pad it.

Comment: &nbsp is not useful. printing &nbsp on mail