# sendmail: passing subject from shell script

Tags: bash, sendmail

i am using a template to send an html file in the body of an email.
now what i want to do is to pass the SUBJECT of the email via command like in the shell script.

My html file looks like this:

```
To: test@test.com
From: noreply@test.com
Subject: subject will change
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
<html>
this is test email body
</html>
```

bash script:

```
email=/usr/sbin/sendmail
report=/opt/html_report.html
template=/opt/email.template

$email -t < $final_report.html
```

Comment: open to suggestions; actually the html file and the header (first four lines) are merged using cat.
the email header is saved as a template in a file and merged everytime a new html report is generated.

Comment: So where does the header come from currently? You could either use sed to translate the subject to what you want, or just use echo to write out the 4 header lines direct from the shell script.

Comment: can you demonstrate a bit; what i understand:
echo To=test@test.com
echo From: noreply@test.com
echo Subject: subject will change
echo Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

Comment: `echo To: test@test,com > final.html` then `echo From:  noreply@test,com >> final.html` etc. But sendmail is probably not the program you are looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the program `sendmail` is the one you want to use here. From the `sendmail` man page:

> Sendmail is not intended as a user interface routine; other programs provide user-friendly  front  ends;  sendmail  is used only to deliver pre-formatted messages.

You probably want to use `/bin/mail` like this:

```
$ mail -s 'insert subject here' recipient@random.com < /opt/b2bpiv/email.template
```

Typing `man mail` or `mail --help` should list all the command-line options you'll need.

Comment: is there an option to send html document in the body; i am taking a look as well on the help. thanks.

Comment: Since you're trying to do this from bash, your html file really only needs the <html> contents.  Subject, To, and From are handled by /bin/mail.  the content file can contain any text you want.

Comment: mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "subject" test@test.com < /opt/report.html
Content-type: text/html: No such file or directory

with -s it sends the report as txt.

Comment: My version of the 'mail' command uses -a for attachments, and it looks like yours is the same (hence the 'No such file or directory') . I usually only use command line mail for text-only stuff, but you might find that mutt (another command line email client) will do what you need.  See Wakaru44's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message