# Mails from Linode VMs kept Landing on Spam Folder

Tags: linux, email, unix, html-email, postfix-mta

I can't explain why email from my `mail` command from my VM kept landing on my **Spam** folder.

```
echo 'test' | mail -s 'test' jdeo@gmail.com
```

## Noticed

- I've noticed that on Linode VMs, mail is not landing on my **Spam** folder.
- When I am on Digital Ocean VMs, emails kept landing on my Spam folder.

I have the same settings.

What should I check further ? How do I make my mail not land in the spam folder ?

Answer (score 1):

The common reason due to which emails from VMs land in SPAMs is either harmful content in email subject / body or unidetified / volatile sender. As far as I understand your DigitalOcean VM Emails get filtered correctly, so that narrows it down towards sender being considered as malicious.

Can you check if both the sender from those 2 different set of VMs are different. If that's the case, then maybe you can use one of the mechanism suggested in this [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200222/set-sender-name-in-mail-function) answer.

Else check if any of the other 2 mechanisms listed in one of a parallel question helps you.

[How to send HTML File in a e-mail Body unis Mailx or mail command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014131/how-to-send-html-file-in-a-e-mail-body-unis-mailx-or-mail-command/61020738#61020738)