# embed clickable link in HTML Outlook Email using bash

Tags: html, bash

I'm writing a bash script that sends an email to users if their AWS key is out of date. I want to include a clickable link to a Service Now ticket they can use to have their AWS keys rotated.

This is the part of the script that sets the text for the email:

```
fusion_link='<a href="https://company.service-now.com/myfusion?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=7949c77e6ffc310048c83cb44b3ee4a7">Change AWS Configuration</a>'
   template1="Hello $first_name, \n\nYour access key: $user_access_key1 for user name: $user_name was created on $date1 and needs to be replaced.\n\nThis key is in AWS Account: $aws_key ($accountnumber).\n\nPlease open up a fusion ticket using this catalog item: $fusion_link to have Cloud Ops rotate your keys.\n\nAll AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days.\n\nRegards,\nCloud Ops"
```

But when the email arrives in Outlook (with HTML turned on) this is the output I get. The link is not formed so that a user can click it:

```
Hello Tim, 

Your access key: AKIAI7EYXZMWBBAOLYJA for user name: tdunphy was created on Thu Jan  4 16:03:32 EST 2018 and needs to be replaced.

This key is in AWS Account: company-ab-nonprod (151528745488).

Please open up a fusion ticket using this catalog item: <a href="https://company.service-now.com/myfusion?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=7949c77e6ffc310048c83cb44b3ee4a7">Change AWS Configuration</a> to have Cloud Ops rotate your keys.

All AWS Keys need to be replaced if they are older than 90 days.

Regards,
Cloud Ops
```

I am sending the email in the bash script using this line:

```
echo -e  "$template1" | /usr/bin/mail -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed for $user_name in $aws_key" "$email_address"
```

The anchor tag is there in the email but it is not clickable. How can I format the link properly so that a user can click it?

Comment: So the anchor tag is there but it isn't clickable, is that what you are saying?

Comment: You have to tell Outlook that the content of your email is HTML. This is done, amoung others, with the `Content-Type` mail header. You don't actually show us how you send the mail, so we cannot see what headers you've included.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've updated the OP for clarity.

Comment: have a look at this question and scroll down to the answers with many upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-to-send-html-email-using-linux-command-line

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will!

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. I appreciate the tip!