# How to sent Email as HTML from bash script by using mail or mailx command (Centos/Redhat)

Tags: bash, html-email, mailx

I am trying to sent an email from bash script which should have HTML table in body , 
I am using mail command in Redhat . but its keep sending me as Text file .

```
difference=`expr $artu_removed - $artu_added`

mail  -s "Built notification" test@gmail.com << EOF


<html>

<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table>  
 <tr>
  <Td> Before </td>  <td>after </td>  <td>differece </td>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <Td> $_before </td>  <td>$_after </td>  <td>$difference </td>
 </tr>

</table>

 Before:$_before
 After:$_after
 Difference:$difference
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Can any one please let me know what shall I do, I am using Redhat, Not ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: See: [How to send HTML email using linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591755/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus, Please see the issues in other comments, I am getting  the HTML table in outlook but its giving this line as text "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Cc: test@outlookcom User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it via mail (do not forget to add your variables):

```
mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "HTML message" test@gmail.com << EOF
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Before </td>
            <td> After </td>
            <td> Differece </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td> $_before </td>
            <td> $_after </td>
            <td> $difference </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    Before: $_before
    After: $_after
    Difference: $difference
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

If you need send from CentOS/RedHat via mailx use it:

```
mail -s "$(echo -e "HTML message\nContent-Type: text/html")" test@gmail.com << EOF
```

Try it for outlook:

```
mail -s "$(echo -e "HTML message\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\nUser-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit")" test@outlook.com << EOF
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <title>Title</title>
...
```

Comment: Thanks I tryed that solution already , its seems mail -a command works in ubuntu but it does not work in Redhat, i get this error                                                  
            Content-type: text/html: No such file or directory

Comment: now email comes but its still same, in email, its showing as text , today i tried both mail and maix but none of them giving me html out put .

Comment: @alammd Maybe because you have no CSS? replace `<body>` to `<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">`. if you get the text then you should just see the HTML tags, true?

Comment: basically, in email, I am  seeing all Text between <<EOF  ......      EOF include the Variable out put . so what we putting inside <<EOF and EOF all comming as Text

Comment: @alammd Where do you get message? gmail? i am trying: gmail.com, mail.ru, and my own mx - all perfectly! (CentOS 7.6.1810 / mailx 12.5-19.el7)

Comment: !!! this is odd, yes in Gmail its fine, but i was trying to get this in outlook , but there its comming as text !! it seems outlook does take this as html, any idea why ?

Comment: !! Thanks for the help, I can see now the table, one problem left,   Along with Table, bellow is coming as TExt value   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit "

Comment: @alammd i am updated again. unfortunately i can not send myself mail in outlook. have problems with the domain. try update.

Comment: with the recent code in out look its the same problem, Can you give me the old one  (before this one ) then lets try to see why that line is comming as text , I really appreciated your help

Comment: @alammd i restored msg. now I will check another variant

Comment: with your last update, it does not work on outlook ( gmail is fine) , it outlook its comes as text totally.

Comment: @alammd the problem is that the outlook doesn't want to understand what content is `text/html`, he is recived `text/plain`, even if present `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: its is understanding, its showing the table in HTML, the out put is fine, but what i dont understand why its showing this line ";Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Cc: test@gmail.com User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii"

Comment: with last one , Full HTML comes as a Text.

Comment: i am not make a test, have a problem with outlook.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through many posts I found a solution for RedHat distros running postfix.  You need to use the -t switch, not the -a switch as in other distros.  Below is an example complete with the email content.  You can copy the entire code example, swap in your information in notepad, and then paste the entire example to a CLI at the $ prompt.

```
mail -t << EOF
From: no-reply@domain.tld
To: uaser@domain.tld
Subject: Some subject here
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    This is normal text.<br>
    <b>This is bold text.</b><br>
    <i>This is text in italics.</i><br>
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```

This solution allows you to use all of the header modifiers and even add attachments if you wish.

Comment: It depends on which `mail` exactly you have installed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188