# Sending logfile content via email on command line – mail is empty

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, sendmail

I am trying to send the contents of a logfile via email like this:

```
sendmail -f deamon@mydomain.tld recepient@mail.com < /private/var/log/mylog
```

Unfortunately, this does not work – the email arrives in the inbox but is empty.

The same is true for this variation:

```
echo "$(</private/var/log/mylog)" | sendmail -f deamon@mydomain.tld recepient@mail.com
```

But when echoing some string like this:

```
echo "testing" | sendmail -f deamon@mydomain.tld recepient@mail.com
```

the email arrives with the content. Also, using `cat` to view the file's content works too. This leads me to the conclusion that is has to be something with the way I wrote the command, but I don't see any syntax problem or similar.

What am I missing – why do the emails arrive empty when trying to send the file contents?

Comment: Could be because of a mail body limitation if your log file is greater than a few megabytes. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333097/how-to-send-a-html-email-with-the-bash-command-sendmail

Answer (score 2):

`sendmail` expects "raw" message (headers and body separated by an empty line) over its standard input.

Try the command below

```
(echo Subject: Logfile; echo; cat /private/var/log/mylog) | sendmail -i -f daemon@mydomain.tld recepient@mail.com
```

`-f daemon@mydomain.tld` - set envelope sender address to `daemon@mydomain.tld`
`-i` - do not treat lines starting with `.` special